# How to sort diseases in descending order for Looker Studio table from Google Sheet columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B4jDCHevvglWc_zRjJP9PteAvD2SMO6DZHsLuysrbIo/edit?usp=sharing) that looks like this:

| Asthma | Urinary Tract Infections |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 |  |
|  | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 |

There are around 50 or so diseases in the above format, the 1 represent positive case on a certain date (kindly refer to google sheet.) I want to display the sum of every disease in descending order. Expected outcome given below.

| Diseases | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Acute (upper) respiratory infections | 4000 |
| Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Diseases | 3454 |
| Asthama | 2300 |
| Sexually Transmitted Diseases | 1200 |

Basically I want a top 10-15 of diseases. I've been trying to make it work somehow but I can't get the diseases to appear row wise. An editable report is given below.
https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/ea611a8e-a6b7-4dd7-96bd-21c17149e1c6
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The shared sheet has restricted access

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I have updated the link, also fixed the date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one (**`alternate`**)approach you may try out; this `requires restructuring (de-pivoting) your raw_data` into the style as in screenshot. the below sheets formula does the heavy lifting to transform the data in one-go & also accounts for any new data you may add to the original raw data tab in the sheet*

```js
=let(rep_,Sheet1!A2:C, grp_,Sheet1!D2:CB, header_,Sheet1!D1:CB1, size_,1,
     Σ,reduce(wraprows(,columns(rep_)+1+size_,),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,{a;{rep_,wrapcols(index(header_,c),rows(rep_),index(header_,c)),choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c))}})),
     filter(Σ,index(Σ,,column(grp_)+1)<>"",--index(Σ,,column(grp_)+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved my entire day.